# MatchEvaluator gives "Cannot use a lambda expression..." error

Tags: c#, regex, lambda, delegates, matchevaluator

I'm modifying the contents of several files. I have this Regex in a form and it's called directly from a button's click event.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code

        if (!OldURLBox.Text.IsEmpty() && !NewURLBox.Text.IsEmpty())
        {
            Regex patternURL = new Regex(string.Format("s:\\d+:\\\\\"((.(?!s:\\d+))*?){0}(.*?)\\\\\";", OldURL));
            content = patternURL.Replace(content, delegate(Match m) // works fine
            {
                var prefix = m.Groups[1].Value;
                var postfix = m.Groups[3].Value;
                var length_prefix = prefix.Replace("\\n", "$").Length;
                var length_postfix = postfix.Replace("\\n", "$").Length;
                var length_total = length_prefix + NewURL.Length + length_postfix;
                return string.Format("s:{0}:\\\"{1}{2}{3}\\\";", length_total, prefix, NewURL, postfix);
            });
        }

        // code
    }
}
```

This is working fine. I've moved this code (regex replace) to another project and getting the following error:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

I'm not calling the regex replace directly inside an event function and I guess that's what causing the error. I don't know how to fix it. Examine the following code. This is the structure I'm using. Omitted irrevelant parts.

```
public partial class ProgressForm : Form
{
    private void ProgressForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // when run without delay, it freezes, waits for targz extraction
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
        timer.Elapsed += (sender2, e2) => OnTimedEvent(sender2, e2);
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (File.Exists(Template.File.ArchiveTarGz))
            {
                // code; extract files from archive

                ModifyFiles();

                // code; repack files
            }
        });
    }

    private void ModifyFiles()
    {
        // code

        Regex patternURL = new Regex(string.Format("s:\\d+:\\\\\"((.(?!s:\\d+))*?){0}(.*?)\\\\\";", Template.Website.URL));
        DBText = patternURL.Replace(DBText, delegate(Match m) // Error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument ...
        {
           var prefix = m.Groups[1].Value;
           var postfix = m.Groups[3].Value;
           var length_prefix = prefix.Replace("\\n", "$").Length;
           var length_postfix = postfix.Replace("\\n", "$").Length;
           var length_total = length_prefix + UserInput.Website.URL.Length + length_postfix;
           return string.Format("s:{0}:\\\"{1}{2}{3}\\\";", length_total, prefix, UserInput.Website.URL, postfix);
        });

        // code
    }
}
```

<sub>This might be a duplicate, because there are other questions with this exact error, but I couldn't find something that I can implement in my code.</sub>

<sub>Someone can change the title to a more suitable one. I didn't want the title to be the error because several questions already exist with that.</sub>

Comment: Naively, your code should compile just fine. However, you have left out the type information on some of the members used in your function, this must be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the contents of DBText. Regex.replace expectes a string as first argument. I am guessing DBText is of type dynamic, which confuses the compiler in this particular case.

You can simply cast DbText to string and you should be fine

```
patternURL.Replace((string)DBText, (...)
```

Comment: Indeed, I was using `var DBText`. Changing it to `string DBText` worked. I was expecting some serious error. Thank you :)